# How to enable the Remember Password option in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox-3.6

I am using Firefox 3.6, but the remember password box is not getting displayed each time I  login to Gmail or any other site where login is required.

I did the same thing in Internet Explorer. There, the Remember Password dialog box is shown.

I really don't want to provide login id and password each time I open a site so please tell me how can I enable the remember password box for Firefox.

Comment: install the latest version. older version likely contain security flaws and are unsafe... plus you get the nicer interface, etc. (typed from Aurora build of mozilla firefox...)

Answer (score 2):

I have FF 4.x but still this applies the same for older version.

Go to

> Tools --> Option --> Security -->
>   Enable 'Remember password on sites'